# Mist hang at downloading new node in rpc mode at first run

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I am trying to use Mist to connect to geth rpc.

First getting geth up running:

```
geth --datadir data --rpc
```

and then run mist with rpc:

`/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc http://localhost:8545`

After Mist opened, the `Download new node...` showed up and it just won't enter the main UI. Mist don't have to sync the blocks since it's a local testnet. How long do I have to wait for it disappears?